# Objectify Blob Read ShortBlob Received Exception

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I am reading App Engine Datastore entry using `objectify` and got the following exception.

```
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod:
    exception occurred while calling backend method (SystemService.java:375)
    com.googlecode.objectify.LoadException: Error loading UserData(5678701068944971):
    At path 'name': Expected class com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Blob,
    got class com.google.appengine.api.datastore.ShortBlob: <ShortBlob: 164 bytes>
```

From the GitHub issue [#284](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/issues/284), this has been addressed in `5.1.11` release, however I am using `5.1.21` release and still getting the issue.

Am I doing something wrong?

The Datastore create is not through `objectify`, it is through Cloud Datastore API. When the Datastore entry is through `objectify` the exception is not seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussion on the issue tracker, we figured out that this was occurring when trying to deserialize a `@Serialize` field. A fix has been made and released as v5.1.22.